# import categories from magento 1 to 2

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-1.8, category, import, export

I need to import categories on magento 2 that I exported from magento 1,
Is it without issue, I mean is it risky for magento 2 store.
Help me please if you have any proposition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the Magento data migration tool.
If you configure it the correct way (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html), this should work without problems.